# How to define a mathematical equation in two parameters in PSTricks?

Tags: pstricks, pst-solides3d

I am to draw a 3D function, using PSTricks' `\parametricplotThreeD`. Coordinate Z in two parameters is so awkward, in terms of controlling  boundary values and formulation that I decided to break it into the affordable functions.

For the mathematical function (as an example),

```
f(t, u) = (1-u)cos(t) + uSin(t/3),
```

I used some of the tex.stackexchange questions and defined my function as, e.g.,

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\usepackage{pst-solides3d}%Drawing
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}%

\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\fMathFunction}[2]
{\FPeval\result{(1-#2)(cos(#1)) + (#2)(sin((#1)/3))}\result}.

\parametricplotThreeD[algebraic, xPlotpoints=20,
linecolor=blue,%
linewidth=0.5pt,plotstyle=curve](0, 1)(0, 1){%
t|\fMathFunction{t}{u}|2+sqrt(\fMathFunction{t}{u})}%

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I get alot af errors.

I would like to know if defining a function in two variables is possible and how it can be utilised. If I moved, then, additionally I like to define another function, say,

```
g(t, u) = 2 + sqrt (f(g, u)),
```

and use it in place of Z.

**Edit 1**: My goal in this question is not drawing. I like to know if it is possible to define a custom mathematical function in two variables. We already know how to define a custom `f(x)`. I like to define a custom `f(x,y)`.

Comment: I assume your last expression should be `g(t,u) = 2 + sqrt(f(t,u))`. Do you have a graphic of what the function should look like?

Comment: Never use the `minimal` class, see [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114)

Comment: @egreg: for PSTricks it makes offen sense  to use the minimal class!

Comment: @Herbert I don't think so.

Comment: My class, actually, is \documentclass[makeidx]{amsbook}. I meant to give a minimal example here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not see how `g(t,u) = 2 + sqrt(f(t,u))` should work with `0..1`. `f(t,u)` can be negative. However, no need for the parametric function:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\psset{viewpoint=30 -50 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=50,lightsrc=viewpoint}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(3,7.5)
\psSolid[object=grille,base=0 3 0 3,action=draw]
\psSurface[ngrid=.1 .1,incolor=yellow,axesboxed,Zmin=-2,Zmax=4,
    linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,
    algebraic,hue=0 1](0,0)(3,3){(1-y)*cos(x)+y*sin(x/3)}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or with a defined function:

```
\def\myFunction(#1,#2){(1-#2)*cos(#1)+#2*sin(#1/3)}
\psset{viewpoint=30 -50 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=50,lightsrc=viewpoint}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(3,7.5)
    \psSolid[object=grille,base=0 3 0 3,action=draw]
    \psSurface[ngrid=.1 .1,incolor=yellow,axesboxed,Zmin=-2,Zmax=4,
    linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,
    algebraic,hue=0 1](0,0)(3,3){\myFunction(x,y)}
\end{pspicture}
```

Comment: I am honoured getting answer directly from Herbert. Nevertheless my question is to put a function myFunction(x,y) defined at the top and then plugged into as (0,0)(3,3){myFunction(x,y)} instead of explicit expression (0,0)(3,3){(1-y)*cos(x)+y*sin(x/3)}.

Comment: `\def\myFunction(#1,#2){(1-#2)*cos(#1)+#2*sin(#1/3)}`  See edited answer